# No se actualizan las propiedadaes de Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

pueden ayudarme no actualiza las propiedades del decorador hasta después de otro dispacth toma el valor.
no se que le pase.

```js
@connect((store) => {
  return {
    adminLogin:store.adminLogin.error
  };
})

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state={
      errors:{},
      user:{
          email:'',
          password:''
        }
    }
    store.subscribe(()=>{
      console.log(this.props.adminLogin)
      this.setState({
        errors:store.getState().adminLogin.error
      })
    })
    this.home = this.home.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.processForm = this.processForm.bind(this);
  }




  home(){
    this.props.history.push('/')
  }

  onChange(e){
    const user = this.state.user;
    const name = e.target.name;
    user[name] = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
      user
    })

  }



  processForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

      // create a string for an HTTP body message
    const email = encodeURIComponent(this.state.user.email);
    const password = encodeURIComponent(this.state.user.password);
    const formData = `email=${email}&password=${password}`;

     this.props.dispatch(postLogin(formData))

   }




  render() {
    return (<LoginCompo
              onSubmit={this.processForm}
              home={this.home}
              user={this.state.user}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              errors={this.state.errors}
             />);
  }

}

export default Login;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
export function postLogin(formData) {

   return function(dispatch){
     const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('post', '/auth/login');
     xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
     xhr.responseType = 'json';
     xhr.onload = () => {
       if (xhr.status === 200) {
         localStorage.setItem('admin',xhr.response.token)
         dispatch({type:'SAVE_TOKEN',token:xhr.response.token})
       } else {
         dispatch({type:'ERROR_LOGIN',error:xhr.response.errors})
       }
     };
     xhr.send(formData);
  }
}
```

```js
export default function reducer(state={
    token:'',
    error:{},
  }, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
      case "SAVE_TOKEN": {
        return {...state, token: action.token}
      }
      case "ERROR_LOGIN":{
        return {...state, error:action.error}
      }
    }

    return state
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué te subscribes al store si ya tienes un connect en el componente? El método *subscribe* lo que hace es añadir un listener para que se ejecute cada vez **se despacha una acción**. Yo no le veo utilidad a ese subscribe, sácalo. Además, edita tu pregunta y coloca el código del action y el reducer para esa acción.

Comment: Para despachar peticiones ajax, ¿usas redux-thunk?

Comment: si pero el problema es que saco el subscribe, pero los ambios de las propiedades del (adminLoginError) no se actualizan es el problema hasta el otro dispatch. Por eso por el momento puse a un subcribe para acutalizar los datos en el state del componenete :!. si utilizo redux-thunk para las peticiones xhr request.

Comment: Ok. Por favor coloca el código de tu action (postLogin) y tu reducer para ver el problema con mayor detalle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo debes saber que el utilitario `connect` recibe tres funciones, la primera -la cual estás usando- mapea tu subscripción a una parte del store a **propiedades** que serán pasadas al componente. Dicho esto, no necesitas tener *en el estado del componente* una variable `errors` porque estos los vas a obtener del store.

> Un componente en React, sea stateless o stateful, se vuelve a renderizar si las props cambian desde el exterior.

Para entender bien cómo funciona la integración entre Redux y React, mirar el siguiente diagrama:

[image]

Commo puedes ver, cada vez que se actualiza el store, el componente subscrito a dicha parte del store que ha sido actualizada, recibe una *actualización* de dichas propiedades del store en forma de props de React, obligando a éste a re-renderizarse.

---

Dentro de tu código, tanto el action como el reducer son correctos (devuelve siempre el store por defecto en un **default case**). El problema radica en tu componente; el cual debe verse así:

```
@connect((store) => ({
  errors: store.adminLogin.error
})
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      user:{
        email:'',
        password:''
      },
    };
    this.home = this.home.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.processForm = this.processForm.bind(this);
  }

  home(){
    this.props.history.push('/')
  }

  onChange(e){
    const user = this.state.user;
    const name = e.target.name;
    user[name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ user });
  }

  processForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // create a string for an HTTP body message
    const email = encodeURIComponent(this.state.user.email);
    const password = encodeURIComponent(this.state.user.password);
    const formData = `email=${email}&password=${password}`;
    this.props.dispatch(postLogin(formData));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LoginCompo
        onSubmit={this.processForm}
        home={this.home}
        user={this.state.user}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        errors={this.props.errors}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Fíjate como le pasamos la prop *errors* que recibimos del store directamente al componente `<LoginCompo />`. Esto permitirá que, cuando ocurra algo malo en la petición y el store se actualice y devuelva los errores como props para `<Login />`, este se re-renderice y los pase directamente al componente `<LoginCompo />`; mostrando los errores que han ocurrido.

Como recomendación final, usa la nueva API [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) para peticiones AJAX ([aquí](https://github.com/github/fetch) tienes un polyfill) y [funciones asíncronas/async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) para un mejor control de tu código.

Comment: Garcia Hola ya funciono perfectamenete era una pregunta que tenia los estados de redux deben ser las unicas o puedo tener locales, al parecer mando el estado directo a los componentes Gracias!

Comment: @valeale Redux no te prohíbe tener un componente stateful (con estado, es decir, una clase que herede de Component), por lo que puedes combinarlos sin problema; sin embargo, debes ser cuidadoso en no mezclarlos, es decir, no hacer que el estado del componente dependa del store. Si usas el estado del componente, úsalo para casos bastante concretos, como el *onChange* de las cajas de texto.

Comment: Garcia excelente bien ahora creare bien mis componetes!